# How WHERE clause works when inserting php variables

Tags: php, sql, where-clause, dynamic-queries

I am having problems trying to get these queries with a WHERE clause to work. I have two tables which look like this :

[image]

[image]

What I am trying to do is return the genre that each film has. At the moment no data is returning at all from what I can see. Here are the two queries:

```
$film_id = $row_movie_list['film_id']; 
mysql_select_db($database_fot , $fot);
$query_get_genre = "SELECT * FROM film_genre WHERE `id_film` ='". $film_id. "'";
$get_genre = mysql_query($query_get_genre, $fot) or die(mysql_error());
$row_get_genre = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_genre);
$totalRows_get_genre = mysql_num_rows($get_genre);

$genre_id = $row_get_genre['id_genre']; 
mysql_select_db($database_fot , $fot);
$query_genre = "SELECT * FROM genre WHERE `id_genre` ='". $genre_id. "'";
$genre= mysql_query($query_genre, $fot) or die(mysql_error());
$row__genre = mysql_fetch_assoc($genre);
$totalRows_genre = mysql_num_rows($genre);
```

PHP with content area. I fairly new to PHP so any help would be appreciated.

```
<?php do { echo $genre['genre']; } while($row_get_genre = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_genre));   ?>
```

Update: I am now able to get first genre but not second it just echos the first one twice and I have tried but still no luck:

```
do {do { echo $row_genre['genre']; } while($row_genre = mysql_fetch_assoc($genre));} while($row_get_genre = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_genre));   ?>
```

Comment: echo $row_get_genre['genre']

Comment: do the $totalRows show a result?

Comment: @dgig Thanks for the reply I echoed out $totalRows_genre the result was 1 for all films  and then $totalRows_get_genre the result was the number of genres found for each film . The problem seems to be with second query maybe something to do the $genre_id not updating?

Answer (score 0):

Avoiding the fact that you're using a deprecated way to establish connection and interact with MySQL, what you're doing is getting a single relation genre-film and then getting the row of the genre that matches. You should surround part of your code with a while that executes while it's still genres of the film with id. Something like:

```
$film_id = $row_movie_list['film_id']; 
mysql_select_db($database_fot , $fot);
$query_get_genre = "SELECT * FROM film_genre WHERE `id_film` ='". $film_id. "'";
$get_genre = mysql_query($query_get_genre, $fot) or die(mysql_error());

while($row_get_genre = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_genre)){
    $genre_id = $row_get_genre['id_genre'];
    $query_genre = "SELECT * FROM genre WHERE `id_genre` ='". $genre_id. "'";
    $genre= mysql_query($query_genre, $fot) or die(mysql_error());
    $row__genre = mysql_fetch_assoc($genre);

   // You should do whatever you want to do with $row__genre here. Otherwise it will be cleared.
}
```

I must insist this is a deprecated and insecure way of communication with a MySQL Database. I recommend you read about MySQLi or PDO extensions.

MySQLi: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

PDO: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php